# Markdown doesn't work on Github suddenly

Tags: github, markdown

I posted README.md for my project as usually, but found it didn't parsed by Github. It displays markdown as is.

Why and how to fix?

Project is here: https://github.com/dims12/DiskPotential

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lines 24 and 26 of your file have a [NUL (U+0000)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) character as part of the GPU description. This should never appear in plaintext files and almost always causes the file to be classified as "not text" (whether by `file` or `grep` or other format-detection tools). It appears that while GitHub itself doesn't mind the NUL character, its markdown interpreter rejects the file.

Comment: This is incredible! null chars are following me! How did you find them? Do you have some simple tool? Neither of my editors / IDEs show them... Thanks